# Unable to call Provable query from my solidity contract in simulator

Tags: solidity, provable

I have this sample contract and I am unable to call updatePrice or updatePricePayable. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I get this below error

> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

I tried deploying contract with ether and without, tried calling method with some wei and without.

My contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI_0.4.25.sol";

contract T2Contract is usingProvable {
    string public ETHUSD;

    constructor() public  {
    }
    
    function __callback(string result) public {
        if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
        ETHUSD = result;
    }
    
    function updatePrice() public  {
        //provable_query("URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price");
        provable_query("WolframAlpha", "random number between 0 and 100");
    }
    
    function updatePricePayable() public  payable {
        //provable_query("URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price");
        provable_query("WolframAlpha", "temperature in london");
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you got is quite generic that means transaction reverted. Did the contract have enough LINK to pay for the query?

Comment: Thanks Ismael, I am new and not sure what LINK is. However as I mentioned I created contract with some ether value and also added wei in value while calling the function. But not sure where I am making mistake. Could you please cccheck this contract in remix if you have time or any other help would be appreciated as I am not sure about where/what I am misssing.  Thanks Anyway for pointer.

Comment: BTW as per Provable - first query should be free anyway. I am still including wei in value.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mistakenly assumed it was chainlink. Where are you testing? ropsten, rinkeby, goerli.